# Infinite multiplicity set of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, computability-theory

### Definitions:

> Fix a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ obtains each value only finite (possibly $0$) number of times. We say $E \subset \mathbb{N}$  is the "multiplicity set" of $f$ iff 
> $1$. For every $n \in E$, there exists at least one value that $f$ takes exactly $n$ times. 
> $2$. If $f$ takes on a value exactly $n$ times, then $n \in E$

In other words, $n \in E$ iff $n$ is the multiplicity of some value under $f$.

> A subset $E $ of $\mathbb{N}$ is said to be "constructable" iff there exists a **continuous** function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $E$ is the multiplicity set of $f$.

### The problem:

> If $E$ is a **computable** subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then is there a way to effectively decide whether or not $E$ is constructable or not?

I asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457544/theorem-about-multiplicity-set-of-continuous-functions) about this almost 2 years ago but only for finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. MSE user "user21820" posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4463682/824088) for the problem which solves the finite case. They also made a conjecture related to the infinite case. So far no progress has been made after that.

Comment: What does "effectively" mean here? do you mean, an algorithm whose input is an algorithm computing $E$ (i.e., telling whether an element is or is not in $E$), and whose output is whether $E$ is "constructable"?

Comment: @YCor Yes. By "effectively decide" I meant "compute".

Comment: OK. Note this is indeed a bit unusual to input an algorithm.

Comment: Doesn't Rice's theorem here mean that there is no way, given an algorithm as input, of doing what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such computable decision procedure, largely because of the same issues underlying [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), as mentioned in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1214047) of Steven Stadnicki. The moral of Rice's theorem is that you cannot compute anything nontrivial about a c.e. set from the program. In this sense, this answer to the question is disappointing, since it is about the limitations of the formalism involving in asking a question about computable sets, rather than about anything having to do with multiplicity sets. Perhaps one might still hope for a characterization of infinite multiplicity sets, despite this negative answer to the question about computably deciding a question about computable sets that you have asked.

Nevertheless, let me explain the answer for this case. What I claim is that one cannot computably decide, given a program $p$ deciding a set $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, whether $E$ is the multiplicity set of some continuous function.

This isn't exactly an instance of Rice's theorem, since we assume that the input program $p$ is the program of a decision procedure for a set $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, in particular, that $p$ halts on every input with either *accept* or *reject*. Nevertheless, the ideas of the proof of Rice's theorem will still apply. Let me explain.

Suppose toward contradiction that we could decide, given a program $p$ computing a set $E\subset\mathbb{N}$, whether or not $E$ is the multiplicity set of a continuous function. Let $e$ be the algorithm for deciding this.

First, let us notice that the set $\{1\}$ arises as the multiplicity set of a continuous function, namely, the identity function. Second, notice that, according to the [answer given at the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457544/theorem-about-multiplicity-set-of-continuous-functions/4463682#4463682), for any $n>0$ the set $\{1,2n\}$ is not a multiplicity set.

Consider the program $p$ that starts out by accepting $1$ and rejecting all other inputs at first. So initially the program $p$ seems to be deciding the set $\{1\}$. It conforms with this policy, all the while running program $e$ on program $p$. (That is, the program $p$ runs $e$ on itself, which looks circular, but this is a standard issue that can be solved with the Kleene recursion theorem. The effect is that it is entirely legitimate to define a program by a process that consults its own code, as I am doing here.)

Since $p$ is acting in accordance with deciding the set $\{1\}$, which is a multiplicity set, the program $e$ must eventually halt on $p$, asserting that it is a multiplicity set. But program $p$ can observe when this occurs, and at this point it switches modes, to accept some large even number $2n$ not yet decided. So the set decided by $p$ will be $\{1,2n\}$, which is not a multiplicity set.

If conversely, $e$ halts on $p$ and says that it is not a multiplicity set, then $p$ carries on with deciding $\{1\}$, which is a multiplicity set.

So in either case, $p$ decides a set of natural numbers, but $e$ gets the wrong answer as to whether it is a multiplicity set or not.

So the question whether the set decided by $p$ is a multiplicity set is not computably decidable.

Comment: What does "the answer given at the other answer" mean?

Comment: I had meant the answer at the other question, to which the OP linked, namely,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457544/theorem-about-multiplicity-set-of-continuous-functions/4463682#4463682. I've edited to explain this better.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I do recognize, alas, that this was not the kind of answer that you sought.